# Significado de error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tengo una página que muestra un mapa gracias a la API de Google Maps. En la página sí se muestra el mapa, pero en la consola sale un Error y me gustaría saber que significa.

> ```
> places_impl.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
>     at Object.k$.j (places_impl.js:42)
>     at zw.<anonymous> (js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:153)
>     at js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:127
>     at Object.<anonymous> (js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:63)
>     at js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:127
>     at Object.<anonymous> (js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:63)
>     at js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:127
>     at js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:63
>     at js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:127
>     at $d (js?key=AIzaSyALlvGlPtW8DZ-gwhfq9lXHOJOt57z5T10&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:65)
> ```

Comment: He publicado una respuesta genérica. Sin ver tu código no es posible darte una respuesta más específica. Lo que usualmente se recomienda es hacer un [mcve] y agregar este a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El significado es: se ha intentado acceder a la propiedad 'ownerDocument' de una variable cuyo valor es null:

```js
let variable=null;
console.log(variable.ownerDocument);
```

Es el equivalente a un Null Pointer Error o NullPointerException de otros lenguajes de programación.